# How to get the windows drive in Powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, syntax

How can one get the drive name that contains the current windows installation in Powershell?

I thought about looping through the DeviceId output of `get-wmiobject -class win32_logicaldisk` and scanning each drive that is returned whether it contains folder `<drive name>/Windows/System32/`.

However I think there is a less convoluted way of finding the drive (which might also be less error prone in case of multiple windows installations on different drives on a single pc).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
(Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).SystemDrive
# C:
```

reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-operatingsystem